# Paypal dialog show me button like "Android_pay_button PayPal" how to fix this error?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, stripe-payments

I try to add PayPal MPL library in my project after implement library everything is working proper but i have only one issue

> Paypal dialog show me button like "Android_pay_button PayPal" but I want only "Pay with Paypal"

how to fix this error?

My Paypal Button looks like this

[image]

but I want like this

[image]

Please help me thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is only occurs when Paypal is not able to detect your application default language so you have to set language manually and syntax for manual language setting

```
payPal.setLanguage(String emailOrPhone);
```

You can read the brief description from below link :
[PayPal Documentation Link](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf)